# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem activesupport with specific versions

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle

I am trying to do a bundle install but am getting the following error: 
`Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    ***private gem*** was resolved to 0.4.2, which depends on
      activesupport (~> 5.0)
    ***private gem*** was resolved to 1.0, which depends on
      activesupport (~> 4)`

**What does this mean?**
I have searched through the internet and getting answers such as do a bundle update, or remove the Gemfile.lock, but none has been working for me.
I have also tried doing a `gem install activesupport -v 4.0` and `gem install activesupport -v 5.0`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually, this kind of error message lists at least two gems. Can you please post the full error message

Comment: looks like it's an issue with rails 4 vs 5 compatibility. something depends on a rails 5 gem (active support 5.0)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have updated the error message, and yes there are two gems